# Robotlegs with SwfSuspenders and AS3Signals

Tags: actionscript-3, robotlegs

a bit confused as to how my XML config file would change when 
switching over to Signals. 
Right now the 3 framework Commands I am using are defined as follows. 
Both ViewChangedCommand and the InitViewCommand are mapped to custom 
events.

```
<type name='app.controller::StartupCommand'> 
    <field name='dataService'/> 
</type> 
<type name='app.controller::ViewChangedCommand'> 
    <field name='event'/> 
    <field name='model'/> 
</type> 
<type name='app.controller::InitViewCommand'> 
    <field name='model'/> 
</type>
```

Answer (score 0):

can't say for sure about the XML config, but here's how to do it in code:

you have to use a SignalContext instead of the normal Context. This can be done using this library :

http://github.com/joelhooks/signals-extensions-CommandSignal/tree/48575b214da452e8c78d9eb2897bd018b1deaf3a

in the context, inject a singleton of the Signal, as if it was part of the model, like so :

```
injector.mapSingleton(DataLoadSignal);
```

then map the signal to a command, like so :

```
signalCommandMap.mapSignalClass(DataLoadSignal, DataLoadCommand, false);
```

for the xml config, I guess you only have to inject the signal, and the rest should be fairly easy.